# Best way of dealing with dropdown list , item not in use, relational integrity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, user-interface

this has come up a couple of times and was wondering how you guys would go about this (apologise if its a duplicate, its was tricky knowing what to search for):

So I have a web app that allows the editing of records. One of the properties of this record is a Guid, which is set via a dropdown list of options.

For this particular app, I need administrators to be able to modify the list of available options in the list of items that the dropdown binds to.

So what is the best way of dealing with a scenario where an administrator removes one of the options from the list (either a true database delete , or via an inUse? bool value change), meaning that any records that hold that value have no matching items in the parent list to bind against.Luckily in MVC the @Html.DropDownListFor helper just sets the selected value to null if the matching option isn't there, avoiding any NullRefExceptions, but then that would (in this case at least) make the ModelState invalid, and would mean that the record would not show up in any select queries based on that value.

Do I add a warning on attempt to delete / disable the option that x number of records would be affected, or disable the amend action entirely unless no records would be affected (requiring all records that hold that value to be amended in advance) ?

Thank you for your input in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. Simplistically, if an admin removes the previously set option, the next time the record is updated, the dropdown will be set to the default or empty option. As long as you're validating that *something* must be picked, then the user will get an error saying that they have to choose an option. It kind of takes care of itself, in a way.

However, relying on users to eventually clean this up is not ideal, to say the least. It's hard to say without specifics about what these options related to, but removing a potential option should not be done on a whim. If there's a valid reason for the removal, then there should also be a replacement in mind. If that's the case, then you can simply run a query to move all the records for the old, no longer available option to the new preferred option. If it's something that is removed and really has no replacement, then the actual foreign key should be nulled out in order to maintain referential integrity. That means the foreign key should be nullable in the first. If there's a business case for it being non-nullable, that should be enforced at the application level in validation, not at the database.

Long and short, after you remove one of the options, your data should be in a consistent state, without the intervention of a user. Then, if the user needs to take some action (because the relationship cannot remain null), you can notify them to come back to the application and select some new option.

Comment: Yep, pretty much what I thought, thanks for taking the time to answer